# Strange wx.CheckBox drawing in wx.ToolBar

Tags: checkbox, wxpython

Here is a code of my toolbar:

```
JS_TOOLBAR_BUTTON = 0
JS_TOOLBAR_SEPARATOR = 1
JS_TOOLBAR_MONTHCONTROL = 2
JS_TOOLBAR_CHECKBOX = 3

def createToolbar(self):
    self.tb = wx.ToolBar(self, style=wx.TB_HORIZONTAL|wx.NO_BORDER|wx.TB_FLAT) 
    self.tb.SetToolBitmapSize((16,16))         
    id=0 
    for toolType,hint,pic,proc in self.toolbarData():
        if toolType==JS_TOOLBAR_BUTTON: 
            id += 10
            self.tb.AddLabelTool(id, hint, pic.GetBitmap(), shortHelp=hint)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, proc, id=id)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL_RCLICKED, proc, id=id)  
        elif toolType==JS_TOOLBAR_SEPARATOR: 
            self.tb.AddSeparator()
        elif toolType==JS_TOOLBAR_CHECKBOX:        
            self.tb.AddControl(wx.CheckBox(self.tb, label=hint))

    self.tb.Realize()       
def toolbarData(self):
    return((JS_TOOLBAR_BUTTON, u"Добавить работника", pictures.add_staff, self.grid.on_insert),                 
           (JS_TOOLBAR_BUTTON, u"Удалить работника",  pictures.del_staff, self.grid.on_delete),        
           (JS_TOOLBAR_SEPARATOR, None,  None, None),
           (JS_TOOLBAR_CHECKBOX, u"Показывать только работающих", None, self.grid.on_delete))
```

As a result I have strange horns outside the checkbox:

[image]

Python 2.7, wx-2.9.2, under Win7x64

Comment: Something has definitely changed with the toolbar rendering in 2.9, but the only information I've been able to find on it deals directly with wxWidgets.  This issue does not occur in 2.8, if you're able to switch.

Comment: My user drawn wxGrid is flickering awfully in 2.8... In the 2.9 everything ok, instead of this trouble. It would be great to find solution here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me is to use CheckLabelTool instead of CheckBox:

[image]

```
self.tb.AddCheckLabelTool(id, hint, pic.GetBitmap(), shortHelp=hint)                
self.tb.ToggleTool(id, self.grid.Table.actualOnly) 
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, proc, id=id)
```